# cPanel Cannot add Addon Domain error says you may not create

Tags: apache, dns, cpanel, whm

When i try to create a new add-on domain under an account with cpanel and the cpanel displays an error

You may not create "the domain that I choose"

Do you know why this happens????

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WHM on GoDaddy you may need to change the owner of the domain in /etc/userdomains.

I recommend raising a support ticket with you hosting provider if you do not have shell access and the error shows no other details.